# Copy single sheet from multiple workbooks to a single workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple Excel files in one folder. I have to extract a single sheet named "sheet 1". (All the files have it, but sheet 1 isn't the only sheet in those workbooks.) Then I have to paste them in a new workbook. (I don't mind if each of them are in different sheet.)

I copied code from the Internet:

```vb
Sub Combine_files()
Dim Path As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Path = "C:\Users\prayag.purohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Project KC\New folder\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
Do While Filename <> ""

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next Sheet

    Workbooks(Filename).Close

    Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: a) Your code doesn't issue such error message. b) Instead of `Sheet("Sheet 1").Copy`, use simply `Sheet.Copy`.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thank you for the help. a)I made the tweaks you suggested, but when I run the code nothing happens now. b)If I change the Sheet("Sheet1") wouldn't that copy all the sheets from every workbook? That would be a mess because each of them contain many sheets.

Comment: You already loop over all sheets in the workbook (using for each). The copy is called for every sheet of the opened workbook. If nothing happens, maybe `Dir` doesn't find anything? Step through your code with F8 and see what happens.

Comment: @FunThomas turns out the error was in the file type. I am supposed to go through macro files, yet used xlsx. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code takes the first sheet in every file and names the sheet to the filename.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Combine_files()
Dim Path As String, Filename As String
Dim wbFile As Workbook, wbActive As Workbook
Set wbActive = ActiveWorkbook
Path = "C:\Users\prayag.purohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Project KC\New folder\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Do While Filename <> ""

Set wbFile = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename, False, True)
wbFile.Sheets(1).Copy After:=wbActive.Sheets(1)
wbActive.Sheets(2).Name = Filename
wbFile.Close SaveChanges:=False

Filename = Dir()
Loop

wbActive.Sheets(1).Select

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```